# How to display CAN frames in php?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get CAN frames and put them in php pages.
I'm using candump command in raspbian so I get the frames with this files :
https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils

candump can0 :

```html
can0 1D01000010 [8] 001000000000000
can0 2D01000010 [8] 001000000000000
can0 2D41000010 [8] 0AF000000000000
can0 2D21000010 [8] 00EF00000000000
can0 1D01000010 [8] 101000000000000
can0 2D01000010 [8] 001000000000000
can0 2D41000010 [8] 0AF000000000000
can0 2D21000010 [8] 00EF00000000000
can0 1D01000010 [8] 001000000000000
can0 2D01000010 [8] 001000000000000
can0 2D41000010 [8] 0AB000000000000
can0 2D21000010 [8] 00EF00000000000
```

So, you see that there is for the moment 4 frames depending on the time and we receive these frames at infinity.

But now I would like to put these frames in a website using HTML and PHP.
So I installed apache in local and it's work great.

I want to have something like this :

http://tech.scargill.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/tmp785C.jpg

I don't know how to attribute each CAN frames in a variable so I can display them.

I made this php file just to get the variable but it doesn't work because I got 4 CAN frames every second in the candump command:

```
<?php 
while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

$proc = popen("candump can0", 'r');
echo '<pre>';
while (!feof($proc))
{
    $a = fread($proc, 1);;
    echo $a;
    @ flush();
}
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

How do you attribut them in variables ?

Comment: Maybe if you provided an example of the output from candump we could advise how to parse it.

Comment: I edited my first post with the example of the output from candump.